# Is there a way to show your hangouts status on your own web page in PHP

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I've found tutorial on how to link to a hangout but I want to show people inbound that I'm online with hangouts so they can contact me.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ether develop a Hangout Extension that can save your personal PHP link page URL, and "tell it" when you enter a Hangout, or just create the PHP link page that you can go to and provide the link info yourself. I suggest a periodic keep-alive rather than count on Hangouts API telling your page as it closes.

Great info to be found in the [Developing with Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/113527920160449995981) community, as well as the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) page in Hangouts API documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did I misunderstand something?